# Method not found for Jackson

Tags: java, maven, jackson

I am trying to start my webapp to WAS 8 and I am seeing the following error....

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/PropertyNamingStrategy;)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper;
at org.springframework.social.facebook.web.SignedRequestDecoder.<init>(SignedRequestDecoder.java:49)
at org.springframework.social.facebook.web.CanvasSignInController.<init>(CanvasSignInController.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
... 41 more
```

From what I have read this is a conflict between versions of Jackson, however, all of my versions appear to be 1.9.9 and the javadocs say that method should exist.

Can anyone help? I am using maven so it could be a dependency chaining issue.

*UPDATE*

Here are the dependencies in my WEB-INF/lib

https://gist.github.com/jrgleason/7932960

Comment: Is any of your other dependencies importing another version of Jackson? It sounds like you have a conflict and the version Java is using is not the one you believe it is using.

Comment: version of Java or Jackson? I tried making sure the classpath was loaded with parent last but that didn't seem to help either. I tried mvn dependency:tree and it only shows the war since I am overlaying.

Comment: I meant Jackson, I am sorry for my mistake. So I have been taking a look a to the different javadoc versions of Jackson at it seems that the `setPropertyNamingStrategy` method was introduced in version 1.8. So, somehow, you are running a version of Jackson older than 1.8. Can you publish the dependencies from your POM?

Comment: Sure but the way it is being built dependency:tree looks like this... [INFO] [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] com.me:backbase-war:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.backbase:portalserver:war:1.0.0SNAPSHOT:compile http://www.backbase.com/portal-software

Comment: I see your list, I am investigating which of those dependencies use Jackson. I will get back to you if I find something.

Comment: If i want to use jackson, i have to get it from maven version 2.2.3. com.fasterxml.jackson.databind Importing it isn't com.codehaus.jackson, but com.fasterxml.jackson. Library is jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this was a missing XML file in my case. So if anyone gets this weird warning it looks like a missing XML file is causing an initialization error that is not propagated very well.

The file (for me) was...

> WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\backbase-portal-business-security.xml